# Как предотвратить схлопывание блока при position: absolute?

Tags: html, css

Привет.

Есть блок, которому необходимо задать  position: absolute, что бы вывести за край контейнера. При добавлении блох схлопывается, и нижний заползает на него. 
Блок резиновый, размер изменяет пропорционально.

Как правильно сделать его?

Как обойти схлопывание?

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/drtvader/jmqchrb1/)

```css
.b-banner-catalog {
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-banner-catalog">
  <div id="banner-catalog" data-ride="carousel" class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="/images/content/catalog-banner.jpg" alt="MacBook Pro 131” Retina" title="MacBook Pro 131” Retina" class="b-banner-catalog__image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b-catalog-category">
  <ul class="b-catalog-category__list">
    <li class="b-catalog-category__item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Электроника" class="b-catalog-category__link"><span class="b-catalog-category__image-block"><img src="/images/content/category-image-1.png" alt="Электроника" title="Электроника" class="b-catalog-category__image"></span><span class="b-catalog-category__header">Электроника</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Position: absolute; подразумевает то, что размеры этого блока теперь не учитываются в контейнере.

Comment: @ВикторЕвлампьев как тогда мне обойти ширину контейнера? выносить за него не вариант, на других разрешения отступы есть.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно если нужно спозиционировать блок с `position: absolute` блоку-родителю ставят `position: relative`.

Comment: если задать родителю relative, то нужный блок опять попадёт в размеры контейнера, а необходимо, что бы он был больше по ширине.

Comment: вы о чём говорите ? смотрите пример https://jsfiddle.net/atlanta/2L1a7fq4/